# Under what circumstance can dy/dx be equal to - 0.11/1 where dy = dx

Tags: calculus, ratio

I'm reading through the book ["Calculus Made Easy" by Silvanus P. Thompson](http://www.gutenberg.org/files/33283/33283-pdf.pdf)

In the page 12, there's an example of a ladder of 181 inches resting against a vertical wall and calculating how much the top end of the ladder goes down as we separate the bottom end of the ladder from the wall, i.e. the ratio where dy decrease while we increase dx

At the end of the example. Silvanus says:

> And the ratio of dy to dx may be stated thus:
>
> $ \frac{dy}{dx} = - \frac{0.11}{1} $
>
> Its also easy to see that (except in one particular position) $ dy $ will be of a different size from $ dx $

I understand that if $ dy = dx $ then:

$ 1 = - \frac{0.11}{1} $

And this doesn't make sense. What particular position is the author referring to?

Comment: At the right isosceles moment, the top of the ladder is falling at the same rate as the foot of the ladder is moving away from the wall.

Comment: Take a look at:https://www.matheno.com/calculus-1/related-rates/how-fast-is-the-ladders-top-sliding/

Comment: @NoChance In your link the horizontal movement of the ladder's bottom end is also different of the vertical movement of the ladder's top end

Comment: @AndrewChin could you explain further? I agree that at the right isosceles moment the horizontal distance to the ladder's bottom is the same as the vertical distance to the ladder's, but as x changes, y doesn't change at the same rate.

Comment: Consider posting a picture of what you have in the book

Comment: @NoChance Added the pdf (the book is free) as I think it can give better context. Page 12.

Comment: You are correct. There is no way $dy$ can be equal to $dx$. One can prove this since the equation:$\:\left(180-k\right)^2+\left(19+k\right)^2-181=0$ has no real roots, where $dy=dx=k$.

Comment: So the "particular position" stated by the author doesn't exist?

Comment: What the above shows is that $dy,dx$ can't be equal given the values of $x=19$ and $y=180$. The phrase "particular position" may refer to a different value of $x$, which will change the value of $y$ since the ladder has the same length, in which case we'll have a different equation that I don't assume it would be easy to solve. As a result, I can't be sure. Maybe if you make your question like is there a value for $x$ where $dy=dx$, it would be more clear.

Comment: Changing the value of $ x $ will always give the same $ dy/dx $ rate for a ladder of 181 inches

Comment: @Jon No, that's wrong. Redo the calculation as the top of the $181$-inch ladder goes from $180$ to $179$ inches above the ground and you'll get a different value for $dy/dx$, and another different value as it goes from $179$ to $178$, and so on. The "particular position" is not when $y=181$ or when $y=180$, but it does exist. As the ladder continues to slide down the wall, $dy$ and $dx$ are always "of a different size" except at one particular position. That position, as has already been said, is at the right isosceles moment.

Answer (score 1):

Let the vertical height of the ladder be $y$ and the horizontal length be $x$

Now, whatever position the ladder may be in, the following is always true by pythagoreas theorem.
$$x^2+y^2=181^2$$
Now when you differentiate the equation with respect to $x$, you get
$$2x+2y{dy\over dx}=0$$ 
$${dy\over dx}=-{x\over y}=-{\cot}{\theta}$$
Now, this rate of change is equal to the instantaneous slope of the ladder. When the ladder is steep (${\tan{\theta}}$ is large), a small increase in $x$ will result in a large decrease in $y$. You can experiment this at home by taking a slab of cardboard and sliding it along the wall and floor of a room. Clearly, the rate of change is equal (${dy\over dx}=1$) only when $x$ is equal to $y$.

Comment: When you take the derivative with respect to $x$ you get $d/dx(x^2)+d/dx(y^2)=2x+0=0$. Also, Note that when $x=y$ $dy/dx=-1$ not $+1$.

Comment: Your differentiation is wrong.

Comment: Isn't $ tan \phi $ = y/x instead of $ x/y $?

Comment: My differentiation is correct. However, if you consider that change in $x,y$ is function of time $t$, then $d/dt(x(t)^2)+d/dt(y(t)^2)=2x(dx/dt)+2y(dy/dt)=d/dt(181)=0$. Check this link:https://www.matheno.com/calculus-1/related-rates/how-fast-is-the-ladders-top-sliding/

Comment: You may refer to your own link to see that my answer is correct. If you think that ${d\over dx}y^2=0$ then please learn some calculus.